# How to affect the way octopus invokes powershell?

Tags: octopus-deploy, octopus

All is working well, except I wish Powershell was invoked with the -NoProfile flag.

Is it possible?

We use Octopus 3.12.6

Answer (score 1):

The [issue 2545](https://github.com/OctopusDeploy/Issues/issues/2545) was marked as resolved in 2016 July and it was added in Octopus [version 3.3.21](https://octopus.com/downloads/compare?from=3.2.21&to=3.3.21).